# For loop inside a function to create m number of functions

Tags: r, function, for-loop

Suppose I have the following function and output:

```
library('pracma')
xlag= c(1,3,5,8,12,16,19,20,22,24)
f1 <- function(beta){ 
  xlag[1]*exp(beta[1] * 1)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3)) + 
  xlag[2]*exp(beta[1] * 2)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3)) +
  xlag[3]*exp(beta[1] * 3)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3))
}
pracma::jacobian(f1,c(1)) 

          [,1]
[1,] 0.8488091
```

I wrote a few for loops in the function so I can extend the model for any value s.

```
h <-function(beta){
  s = 1:3
  xlag= 1:9
  n <-c()
  for (i in s) {
    n[i] <- exp(beta[1] * s[i])
  }
  sal <-sum(n)
  z <-c()
  for (i in s) {
    z[i] <- xlag[i]*exp(beta[1] * s[i])/sal
  }
  sum(z) 
}
pracma::jacobian(h,c(1))

          [,1]
[1,] 0.8488091
```

Now I would like to write f for xlag[1:3], xlag[4:6] xlag[7:9].
Such that the Jacobian becomes a matrix with 1 column and 3 rows. Where the first entry is the one specified above. And the second entry is:

```
f2 <- function(beta){ 
  xlag[4]*exp(beta[4] * 1)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3)) + 
  xlag[5]*exp(beta[5] * 2)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3)) +
  xlag[6]*exp(beta[6] * 3)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3))
}
pracma::jacobian(f2,c(1)) 
         [,1]
[1,] 1.697618
```

The third entry:

```
f3 <- function(beta){ 
  xlag[7]*exp(beta[4] * 1)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3)) + 
  xlag[8]*exp(beta[5] * 2)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3)) +
  xlag[9]*exp(beta[6] * 3)/(exp(beta[1] * 1)+exp(beta[1] * 2)+exp(beta[1] * 3))
}
pracma::jacobian(f3,c(1))

         [,1]
[1,] 0.706992
```

So I would like h to output:

```
          [,1]
[1,] 0.8488091
[2,] 1.697618
[3,] 0.706992
```

The jacobian function is structured as follow

```
library('pracma')
jacobian(f, x0, heps = .Machine$double.eps^(1/3), ...)
f: m functions of n variables.
x0: Numeric vector of length n.
heps: This is h in the derivative formula.
jacobian(): Computes the derivative of each function f_j by variable x_i separately, taking the discrete step h.
```

So I need 3 functions f1,f2,f3 of one variable. Yielding a matrix of 1 column and 3 rows.
Could anyone help me rewrite h such that I get the desired output?

Comment: Why not define f as `f(beta, lag_start)`?
Then `xlag[lag_start]`, `...`, `xlag[lag_start+2]`.

Comment: Hmmm. Then I would have to add them together manually afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
h <-function(beta){
  s = 1:3
  xlag #total set of xlag variables
  u =1:(length(xlag)-length(s)) #basis for loop
  n <-c()
  for (i in s) {
    n[i] <- exp(beta[1] * s[i]) #nominator expo almon 
  }
  sal <-sum(n) #denominator expo almon
  z <-c()
  for (i in s) {
    z[i] <- exp(beta[1] * s[i])/sal #expoalmon
  }
  final <-c()
  for (i in u) {
    final[i] <- sum(xlag[(i):(i+2)]*z[1:3])
  }
  final
}
pracma::jacobian(h,c(1))
```